# registro con usuario logueado en adminlte laravel

Tags: adminlte

¿Alguien que trabaje con adminlte en Laravel sabe como activar la ruta "register" una vez hecho login en el sistema? Necesito que solo un usuario administrador pueda dar de alta nuevos usuarios.

Comment: Por favor, revisá [ask]. Además, la etiqueta _adminlte_ no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, ya que lo que buscabas hacer era con Laravel.

Comment: OK, gracias, me repaso las normas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final todo era cambiar la siguiente línea en RegisterController.php, de guest a auth

```
    $this->middleware('auth');
```